# Spivak's Calculus: Using derivatives prove that if $n \geq 1$, then $(1+x)^n > 1+nx$ for $-1<x<0$ and $x>0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following is a problem from Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11

> 65. Use derivatives to prove that if $n \geq 1$, then
>
> $$(1+x)^n > 1+nx, \text{ for } -1<x<0 \text{ and } x>0$$
>
> (notice that equality holds for $x=0$)

The solution in the solution manual is a bit terse

> Let $g(x)=(1+x)^n-(1+nx)$. Then $g(0)=0$, but $$g'(x)=n(1+x)^{n-1}-n\tag{1}$$
>
> Since $n-1 \neq 0$ this means that
>
> $$\begin{align}g'(x) & < 0 \text{ for } -1<x<0, \\ & >0 \text{ for }
>  x>0 \end{align}\tag{2}$$
>
> Thus $g(x)>0$ for $-1<x<0$ and $x>0$

I'd like to fill in the the steps in more detail. Also, my solution differs from the solution above and I'd like to know why.

Consider, for example, the case $n=2$. Then

$$g(x)=(1+x)^2-(1+2x)$$
$$g'(x)=2(1+x)-2$$
$$g(-1.5)=(1-1.5)^2-(1+2\cdot (-1.5))=\frac{1}{4}+2>0$$
$$g'(-1.5)=2(1-1.5)-2=-3$$

**Why doesn't the solution account for the interval $(-2,-1)$?**

Here is what I mean.

Consider $(1)$

$$g'(x)=n[(1+x)^{n-1}-1]$$

$$g'(x)<0 \implies (1+x)^{n-1}-1<0$$
$$\implies (1+x)^{n-1}<1$$

If $n-1$ is odd, then

$$1+x<1 \implies x<0$$

If $n-1$ is even, then

$$1+x<1 \implies x<0$$ or $$1+x>-1 \implies x>-2$$

Therefore, for any $n\geq 1$

- if $n$ is even, then $g$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and increasing on $(0,\infty)$. $0$ is a local minimum.
- if $n$ is odd, then $g$ is decreasing on $(-2,0)$ and increasing on $(\infty,-2)$ and $(0,\infty)$. Therefore, there is another root of $g(x)$ other than $0$. $0$ is a local minimum, $-2$ is a local maximum.

Therefore

- if $n$ is even, $g(x)>0$ for all $x \neq 0$
- if $n$ is odd, $g(x)>0$ for all $x$ above some value $x_0$ such that $g(x_0)=0$, excluding $0$.

**Is my reasoning incorrect or is the solution manual incorrect?**

[image]

Comment: What you're worrying about seems highly irrelevant. The question deals only with $x>-1$ and $x\ne 0$. Using $g(0)=0$, he deduces from the fact that $g$ is decreasing on $(-1,0)$ that $g(x)>0$ for $-1<x<0$, and from the fact that $g$ is increasing on $(0,\infty)$ that $g(x)>0$ for $x>0$. End of argument.

Comment: Yes but why would the question restrict the result in such a way if the answer can be more general? Having completed over 350 problems in Spivak so far, it seems unusual to me compared to the other problems. Furthermore, the restriction makes me question if my attempt at a more general answer is even correct. Is it?

Comment: @evianpring You have to assume $n>1.$

Comment: Consider $n=3/2$.  Then $(1+x)^n$ is not defined (or not a real number) when $x<-1$.  But the claimed result is still true when $n$ is any real number ${}\ge 1$.

Comment: And if we assume $n$ is integer, the inequality is in general not true for $x < -1$. Take $x = -4$ and $n = 3$.

Comment: I think @GEdgar noted the reason why I was confused. I was assuming $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc also makes a good point: if $n=1$ then $g(x)=0$ for all x. Therefore, the problem should have stated $n>1$.

Comment: @sku, if we assume $n$ is an integer (same as assuming it is a natural number in this problem since $n>1$), then the inequality is true for a larger interval than $(-1,0)$. I believe in this case the graphs I posted in my question depict the situation correctly, yes?

Comment: The remaining question I have is how the solution manual proof goes from $(1)$ to $(2)$?

Comment: @evianpring yes but it loses the generality. That is it works for some $n$ and not others.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this holds is the convexity of $(1 + x)^n$. The line $y = 1 + nx$ is the tangent line to the graph of $y = (1 + x)^n$ at $(0,1)$ and the solution given is a long-winded way of saying the graph of a convex function lies above its tangent line, essentially using that its second derivative is positive. Note $n$ has to be strictly greater than $1$ for the exercise to hold true.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of proof without derivative ... 
$(1+x)^n > 1+ nx$ means that $(1+x)^n - 1^n > nx$
Now, factoring the right hand side we get
$x[1 + (1+x) + (1+x)^2 + ... +(1+x)^{n-1}) > nx$
so, when $x> 0$ this reduces to:
$[1 + (1+x) + (1+x)^2 + ... + (1+x)^{n-1}] > n$
which is of course true.
But if $x$ is negative (and $>-1$) dividing by $x$ changes sign so
we get
$[1 + (1+x) + (1+x)^2 + ... + (1+x)^{n-1}] < n$
which also holds.

Comment: In fact, Spivak's text proves it without derivatives (for integer $n$) way back at the beginning of the book.  Proof by induction on $n$.  The proof uses little more than the axioms of ordered field.